# How to ensure that a column in dataframe loaded from a csv file is formatted as an integer (without decimal characters)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am using Python 3.7

I need to load data from two different sources (both csv) and determine which rows from the one sources are not in the second source.

I have used pandas data-frames to load the data and do a comparison between the two sources of data.

I loaded the data from the csv file and a value like 2010392 is turned to 2010392.0 in the data-frame column.

I have read quite a number of articles about formatting data-frame columns; unfortunately, most of them are about date and time conversions.

I came across an article "Format integer column of Data-frame in Python pandas" at http://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/format-integer-column-of-dataframe-in-python-pandas/ which does not solve my problem

Based on the above mentioned article I have tried the following:

```
pd.to_numeric(data02['IDDLECT'], downcast='integer')

Out[63]: 
0         2010392.0

1       111777967.0

2         2010392.0

3         2012554.0

4         2010392.0

5         2010392.0

6         2010392.0

7         1170126.0
```

and as you can see, the column values still have a decimal point with a zero.

I expect the load of the dataframe from a csv file to keep the format of a number such as 2010392 to be 2010392 and not 2010392.0

Here is the code that I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("timetable_all_2019-2_groups.csv") 
data02 = data.drop_duplicates()

print(f'Len data {len(data)}')
print(data.head(20))

print(f'Len data02 {len(data02)}')
print(data02.head(20))

pd.to_numeric(data02['IDDLECT'], downcast='integer')
```

Here is a few lines of the content of the csv file:
The data in the one source looks like this:

```
IDDCYR,IDDSUBJ,IDDOT,IDDGRPTYP,IDDCLASSGROUP,IDDLECT,IDDPRIMARY

019,AAACA1B,VF,C,A1,2010392,Y

2019,AAACA1B,VF,C,A1,111777967,N

2019,AAACA3B,VF,C,A1,2010392,Y

2019,AAACA3B,VF,C,A1,2012554,N

2019,AAACB2A,VF,C,B1,2010392,Y

2019,AAACB2A,VF,P,B2,2010392,Y

2019,AAACB2A,VF,C,B1,2010392,N

2019,AAACB2A,VF,P,B2,1170126,N

2019,AAACH1A,VF,C,A1,2010392,Y
```

Comment: Have you tried using [pandas dtype option on reading csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)?

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? I can't reproduce this with 0.23.4.  If I just call `read_csv` (and pass it only the filename) then `df.dtypes` shows `int64` for the `IDDLECT` column

Comment: Did you try df['IDDLECT']=df['IDDLECT'].astype(int)

Comment: I am using Spyder 3.3.3 via Anaconda; according to the Environments in Anaconda that I am using the pandas version is 0.24.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have data which is not of integer type. Once loaded you should do something about that data and then convert the column to int.

From your error description, you have nans and/or inf values. You could impute the missing values with the mode, mean, median or a constant value. You can achieve that either with pandas or with [sklearn imputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html), which is dedicated to imputing missing values.

Note that if you use mean, you may end up with a float number, so make sure to get the mean as an int.

The imputation method you choose really depends on what you'll use this data for later. If you want to understand the data, filling nans with 0 may destroy aggregation functions later (e.g. if you'll want to know what the mean is, it won't be accurate).

That being said, I see you're dealing with categorical data. One option here is to use `dtype='category'`. If you want to later fit a model with this and you leave ids as numbers, the model can conclude weird things which are not correct (e.g. the sum of two ids equals to some third id, or that ids that are higher are more important than lower ones... things that a priori make no sense and should not be ignored and left to chance.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Because the data is not for analysis purposes in a model, I have decided to remove the rows with missing values from the source.

Answer (score 0):

```
data02['IDDLECT'] = data02['IDDLECT']fillna(0).astype('int')
```

Comment: I have tried this just now and got the following error: 
  File "C:\Users\phlip\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 676, in astype_nansafe
    raise ValueError('Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to '

ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Comment: You need to replace all the 'nan' values.  Try data02['IDDLECT'].fillna(0)

Comment: You have null values in your data set. You can use fill a to replace them with zeros or another number and then covert.

Comment: data02['IDDLECT'] = data02['IDDLECT'].fillna(0).astype('int')

Comment: Of the 6900 records in the csv file, 21 records did not have a value in the ['IDDLECT'] field. After I have removed these 21 records from the data-set, the values were loaded correctly. Sorry for a lack of data checks but thanks for your help